# webdriver-manager update throwing Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm getting ETIMEDOUT error while installing **webdriver-manager updated**. Find the error details as below:

```
C:\Users\....> webdriver-manager update

webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
events.js:160

      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT XX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXX

at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
```

Also when I tried to ping the host `XX.XXX.XX.XXX`. Got **`Destination net unreachable`** message. Could you please anyone help me to overcome this issue.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes I'm behind the proxy.

Comment: Then that is your problem. Your proxy doesn't allow you to go the to addresses to download the binaries. What you can do is check if you can provide alternative addresses that are allowed by your proxy. Enter `webdriver-manager --help` to see the command for that and search the web for CDN locations for the binariers. You need to test them by hand if they will pass your proxy

Comment: Oh okay... Thanks let me try...

Comment: Bypassing the proxy is depending our your own proxy, that a specific thing. Try the part I described above or discuss it with the firm the proxy belongs to, to be able to access the correct locations

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By giving the below comment I can update the webdriver-manager:

`webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx:8080`

Thanks all for the comments.

Comment: If you get Error: unable to get local issuer certificate then add the flag --ignore_ssl before the --proxy