# Protractor: ng e2e: How to solve the "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT" error?

Tags: angular, protractor, angular-cli

I developed the [Tour of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1) Angular tutorial application. After that I wrote tests for the components. The application and the component tests are doing fine. Now I wanted to develop E2E tests with Protractor and I can't get them running.

Every time I run `ng e2e` on the command line, I get the following output:

```
$ ng e2e
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49152, open your browser on http://localhost:49152/ **
Date: 2017-09-26T14:51:12.962Z
Hash: ef70100f8d31703b6b85
Time: 8035ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 3.16 MB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 209 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.6 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
(node:13556) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

webpack: Compiled successfully.
events.js:182
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 216.58.205.112:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1174:14)
```

Some hopefully useful information regarding my setup:

- The project was created with the Anguliar CLI
- Protractor was installed globally and local
- The following files are in the `node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium` directory: `chromedriver_2.32.exe, chromedriver_2.32.zip, chrome-response.xml, gecko-response.json, selenium-server-standalone-3.5.3.jar, standalone-response.xml`
- I run `webdriver-manager update` with a proxy property
- It makes no difference if I run the command with a running Selenium Grid or with the `directConnect: true` configuration
- As browser is set Chrome (Firefox has the same problem)
- OS: Windows 10, Browser: Chrome 51.0.2704.106 m (64-bit)

`protractor.conf.js` file:

```
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  /*seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',*/
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: 'e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json'
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({ spec: { displayStacktrace: true } }));
  }
};
```

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "angular-tour-of-heroes",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.2.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "^0.4.6",
    "codelyzer": "~3.1.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

It's the first time that I try to develop E2E tests with Angular and Protractor.

Thank you for your support!

**Update**

I didn't know that `webdriver-manager update` will be executed if I run `ng e2e`. So I tried `ng e2e --no-webdriver-update` and with this command the error above is not coming anymore. I think the error appears because no proxy is set and the webdriver-manager is not able to run the update.

However, now I am getting a new error. Here is the full output again:

```
$ ng e2e --no-webdriver-update
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:49152, open your browser on http://localhost:49152/ **
Date: 2017-09-27T06:50:31.482Z
Hash: ef70100f8d31703b6b85
Time: 8513ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 3.16 MB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 209 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 11.6 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
(node:12764) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.

webpack: Compiled successfully.
[08:50:31] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[08:50:31] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[08:50:31] E/direct - Error code: 135
[08:50:31] E/direct - Error message: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
[08:50:31] E/direct - Error: Could not find update-config.json. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.
    at Direct.getNewDriver (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:63:31)
    at Runner.createBrowser (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\built\runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (D:\gitrepos\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[08:50:31] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 135
```

Answer (score 10):

OK, I was able to solve the problem. Here is what I did.

`ng e2e` runs the `webdriver-manager update` command. In my case this caused the `ETIMEDOUT` problem, because in my environment without a proxy it cannot download the files. Instead I have to use `ng e2e --no-webdriver-update`.

Now I had the `Could not find update-config.json` error.

Using the `--proxy` argument to update webdriver-manager seems to not download everything and/or correct. I had to set the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` and run the command `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl`.

Now protractor is working.

Comment: This works! I set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to my corporate proxy, than created a new project using the Angular CLI. Now I could run the tests by simply using the ng e2e command, and didn't need to disable the webdriver update and/or update it manually with the --proxy flag.

Answer (score 4):

I found that `webdriver-manager update` respects `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable. Try to setup `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable with your (corporate) proxy server `http://********:80` Restart your VS Code or command prompt (to pickup changes) and you should be fine to run e2e tests without issues.

Comment: did the trick for us, indeed if you are behind corporate proxy, this will solve the problem of driver update

Answer (score 2):

If you are in webstorm or Intellij editor. You can either setup the HTTPS_PROXY variable or in the webstorm terminal

```
SET https_proxy=http://yourcompanydomain.com:portnumber
SET http_proxy=http://yourcompanydomain.com:portnumber
```

Then run the following command in Terminal

```
ng e2e
```

it should definitely work

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was related to a company proxy. The `webdriver-manager update` command was hitting the timeout. Neither setting the proxy in the .npmrc nor by using the command line like below didn't work.

**Not working solution:**

```
SET http_proxy=http://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx:8080

SET https_proxy=http://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx:8080
```

**Working solution:** provide the command with a `--proxy` flag:

```
webdriver-manager update --proxy=http://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx:8080
```

This is the correct answer from [webdriver-manager update throwing Error: connect ETIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180407/webdriver-manager-update-throwing-error-connect-etimedout)